# Bit-field struct within bit-field struct in C

Tags: c, structure, field, bit

I'm trying to find another way to create a bit-field structure within a bit-field structure in C.

Somewhat like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int A : 16;
  int B : 16;
} Struct1;

typedef struct
{
  int A     : 16;
  Struct1 B : 32;
} Struct2;
```

But the C Compiler doesn't like it, and it has to be bit-field.
A friend came up with using unions, but was wondering if someone knows another method besides using unions for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need/want to do this?

Comment: Why cant you use one struct and be done with it?

Comment: I'm translating code from ADA to C, and we're trying to do it as close as possible to the ADA as we can

Comment: @shunyo -- we did that for some structures, but can't do that will all of them

Comment: @ryyker good questoin let me check

Comment: because Struct1 defines a bit field, In your second struct, if : 32; is replaced with ;, does Struct1 B; not also define a struct member that is a bit field?  i.e.: `Struct2 abc;`    `abc.A = 0x22;`  `abc.B.A = 0x22;` and `abc.B.B = 0x44;` all seem to accept values and are useable like a bitfield.

Comment: yep, so far that seems to do the trick !! thanks!

Comment: I put an answer below that is a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If I do this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int A : 16;
  int B : 16;
} Struct1;

typedef struct
{
  int A     : 16;
  Struct1 B;
} Struct2;
```

then

```
Struct2 abc;

abc.A = 0x1111;

abc.B.A = 0x1123;

abc.B.B = 0x3334;
```

accepts assignments and can be used like bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815677/nested-structures) might be of assistance to you. Ofcourse you have to change the declarations a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Ryyker's comment seemed to do the trick! Just remove the bit-field declaration on Struct1, still needs some testing but we'll see.